# using result from CONCAT and LIKE clause

Tags: php, cakephp

I just want a simple explanation on what does this CONCAT and LIKE does in this code. Thank you.

```
$data = $this->request->data;
    $conditions = array('authenid' => $data['id'], 'isblacklist' => $data['isblacklist']);

    if( $data['key'] == "msisdn" ) {
        if(isset ($data["search"])){
            if( trim($data["search"]) != "" ) {
                $conditions[ "CONCAT(msisdn,',',ton,',',npi) LIKE" ] = "%".trim($data["search"])."%";
            }
        }
        $tmpData = $this->blkwhtlist_msisdn->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => $conditions
        ));
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying querys in **mysql** db:

**CONCAT** is a string function to concatenate in mysql:

```
CONCAT('abc', '.de') that return a string 'abc.de'
```

And the **LIKE** is a mysql operator used to select data based on patterns. Therefore the LIKE operator is often used in the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement. mysql provides two wildcard characters for using with the LIKE operator, the percentage % and underscore _.

- The percentage ( %) wildcard allows you to match any string of zero
  or more characters.
- The underscore ( _) wildcard allows you to match
  any single character.